# GAS スプレッドシートのボタンでリンクを取得

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

スプレッドシートを作成し、その中の「完了ボタン」を押すことでリンクを取得することはできないでしょうか、

始めたばかりで、わからないことが多くあったので質問させていただきました。
情報が少なく申し訳ありません。
したいことはわかるのですが、その為の手段がわからないのでどなたかご助力お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Scriptを利用して「URLを表示」というメニューを作る例を作成してみました。

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu("URLを表示")
    .addItem("URLを表示する", "alertUrl")
    .addToUi();
}

function alertUrl() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var url = ss.getUrl();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(url);
}
```

以下のようなメニューが表示され、……
[image: メニュースクリーンショット]

クリックすると以下のようなウィンドウが表示されて、URLをコピーすることが出来ます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

参考までにどうぞ。

Answer (score 0):

どういった仕様なのが不明確な点はありますが、
Google Apps Scriptを利用すれば解決するのではないでしょうか。

ボタンの設置はこちらを参考に
http://stabucky.com/wp/archives/7337

スクリプトの構築例はこちらが参考になります
スプレッドシートのURLを取得する
http://nevernoteit1419.blogspot.jp/2012/01/idurl.html